# Refresh app's XCUIElementQuery after screen updates

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing UI tests for my application.
How can I refresh list of `app.buttons`/`app.otherElements`, after screen has been updated?

Example:
I'm pushing login button on login screen, waiting for server response.
After response arrived I see another screen and need to push button on it, but `button.exists == NO`.

Should I make new instance of app(`[[XCUIApplication alloc] init]`) each time when screen updates?

Answer (score 2):

You should grant the button that you want to tap after signing in an accessibilityIdentifier, and then wait for that to exist. This ensures that you won't try to interact with your app until the new UI has loaded, not just that the old UI has gone away.

I strongly recommend extracting the "wait for this element to appear" functionality into a test helper, per Joe Masilotti's excellent guide that can be found [here](http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/) (though you will have to reimplement them in ObjC, as he wrote them in Swift).

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the login operation to complete by waiting for a unique element on the login screen to *not* exist.

```
XCUIElement *logInButton = app.buttons["signInButton"];

// Tap the log in button
[logInButton tap];

// Wait for the login operation to complete
NSPredicate *notExistsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exists == false"];
[self expectationForPredicate:notExistsPredicate evaluatedWithObject:logInButton handler: nil];
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10.0 handler: nil]; // Adjust timeout as needed
```

This will ensure that the view hierarchy available on XCUIApplication is refreshed when the screen contents change.